# java parameter in jsp:include

Tags: jspinclude

I wanted to know if I can pass a java variable to a . I tried to do something like this inside a jsp file:

```
<% String folder = request.getParameter("something"); %>
<jsp:include page="../<%=folder%>/myframe.jsp" ></jsp:include>
```

This does not work. I get an error which says 'Failed to find resource /=folder/myframe.jsp'.
Can this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like it can't be done. However, you can [send parameters](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref1112.html) to an included page.

Comment: Yes, that way is straight forward. However I wanted to do it the above mentioned way. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You either need to have the page parameter as an entire string or as an entire substitution.

```
<jsp:include page="<%= myPageToInclude %>" />
<jsp:include page="path/to/my/page.jsp" />
```

Also when concatenating strings inside a value you need to escape the double quotes.
So for your problem :

```
<% String folder = request.getParameter("something"); %>
<jsp:include page="<%= \"../\" + folder + \"/myframe.jsp\" %>" />
```

Should work fine, or for easier reading :

```
<% 
    String folder = request.getParameter("something");
    String page = "../" + folder + "/myframe.jsp";
%>
<jsp:include page="<%= page %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Concidering your param name as "something",
Try this:

```
<jsp:include page="../${param.something}/myframe.jsp" />
```

Other solution is to do that:

```
<% String folder = request.getParameter("something"); %>
<% pageContext.setAttribute("folder", folder); %>

<jsp:include page="../${folder}/myframe.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

First is better but both should works.