# Calling user defined functions in bean using JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, javabeans

I have a method

```
public void X(HttpServletResponse response)
```

in my bean. I want to call that function in JSP using JSTL. How can I do that? I just have to call the function.It does not return any value.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566410/invoking-a-java-method-in-jsp

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using custom tags. You can put all utility methods in a class as static and then expose them using tld file. Then include that tld in your JSP and then you can call the method using EL as -

```
${util:myMethod(anyParameter)}
```

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html) for custom tags.